# Jenkins Git plugin polling

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have an issue which I think is due to the Git plugin.

I have a set of jobs which are to be run **only** when triggered remotely. To achieve this, under the build triggers section I selected only the "Trigger builds remotely" option, leaving everything else is turned off (even the "Poll SCM" option). However this is not working, as I have some jobs that keep starting up without any apparent reason. Moreover, when I look at "false" build logs, the very first line says "Started by an SCM change".

I guess that this is due to the Git plugin which is polling for changes on the repo. Here is my question: why would the Git plugin keep polling the repo when I explicitly said that the job should **NOT** be triggered by Polling the SCM?

Comment: Is this a multi-branch pipeline job, freestyle job, or regular pipeline job?

Comment: It's a freestyle job created using the Job DSL plugin

Comment: Any ideas @RobHales ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also check your job scripts, which uses `git` plugin: there is parameter `poll: false` for disabling polling for an SCM checkout

Examples:

- If you are using `Git`:

`git branch: 'your_branch_name', changelog: false, credentialsId: 'your_git_credentials_in_jenkins', poll: false, url: 'http://localhost:7990/scm/test/your_repo.git'`

- If you are using `GitSCM`:

`checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name:'*/your_branch_name']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'your_git_credentials_in_jenkins', url: 'http://localhost:7990/scm/test/your_repo.git']]]`

You can use [snippet generator](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator) to get example of parameters and their default values for your SCM